# My ATI graphics card gets very hot and Ubuntu freezes

Tags: ati

I`m Using 12.10 on my Desktop. It constantly Freezes.

The graphics card is really very hot. I can't even touch it.    :(

Comment: Did it work with another OS? Have you checked your fans are not clogged? Is this even a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your fans running fast, but your GPU is still hot?

If this is the case, you should check for dust and remove it. I've encountered several cases where the cooler was clogged so badly that very little air passed through it, even though the fan was running at maximum speed. Try removing the fan and then carefully use a vacuum cleaner to remove all the dust.

If there is no clogging and the fan is spinning slowly, the problem could be the fan itself. Too much dust inside the fan itself could be a problem. Spraying some oil into it might help, or you could just replace the fan completely.

Comment: haha you know one thing my graphic card (ati)

had no fan

Only Heat Sink Is There :( no fan

Comment: What model is it? Is it normally supposed to have a fan? Either way, I would consider installing some fans in the case itself. It really helps keep the temperature down. Try to get air flowing around the graphics card.